# black screen / low graphics mode on logout

Tags: lightdm, fglrx, logout

If log out from session, get black screen and the "low graphics mode" dialog, sometimes with cursor, sometimes without.

14.04 with latest fglrx. Dual head Pavillion dv6-6051er.

ONLY when log out. Reproduced 100%. Had no such problem with 13.10.

Any ideas/workarounds?

Could be a copy of: http://www.mail-archive.com/desktop-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg310676.html

UPDATE. Can't start a console session with ctr+alt+f1 once the "low graphics mode" dialog appears.

UPDATE 2. Question also posted on the AMD Developers' Forum: http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/168615

UPDATE 3. Is it possible to make lightdm kill and restart the X server upon logout? Maybe will help. Checked here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918649 - but didn't see an appropriate lightdm.conf option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be a solution to your question nor a very satisfying workaround, but I have the same issue since Ubuntu 14.04 and find that when I log out while using integrated graphics (Intel HD 4400) Ubuntu turns to low graphics mode, but when switching to discrete graphics (Radeon HD 8670M) log out works fine.

I use proprietary drivers (fglrx) for the discrete graphics card and catalyst control centre to switch between both GPUs. When I log out while using the discrete GPU, the screen flickers a bit (it looks like something is happening to screen resolution) before it brings me to the login screen, but it works.

Update:
I removed fglrx and set my laptop to use only the integrated GPU in BIOS. Now I can actually log out when using the integrated GPU. There is no possibility left to switch to the discrete GPU however.

If the same is possible on your machine (setting it to integrated graphics only) you can get low power consumption back.

Comment: Maybe expand on this a bit? How do you switch etc.? Please write your answer in more detail. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu :)

Comment: I added some details, but I am not an expert here so I could have left out relevant information. I'd be happy to answer other more specific questions.

Comment: Thank you for adding the information, I'm sure it will be helpful. Thanks also for helping us out, you can many [unanswered questions](http://askubuntu.com/unanswered) around the site. Have a great day :)

Comment: Switching to ATI graphics does make a difference, it seems to log out normally, even if prompts to report an error when I log back in. Not a very satisfying workaround as you said, battery life difference is big..

Comment: Hi Pavel, I edited my answer to contain a workaround that does preserve low power consumption with integrated graphics, being able to log out. At the cost of being able to use the discrete GPU, though.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know if this answer is still valid after all that time but I was suffering the same problem (Dell Inspiron 15R, ATI Radeon HD8xxxM series, kubuntu 14.04.1 - 64 bits).

The flaw disappeared after installing the 14.6 beta driver from Ati. Link below:
http://support.amd.com/pt-br/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64#1